# How to change modified time of copied file in destination

Tags: powershell

I am using powershell to copy files into a folder, but I want to update the modified time [LastWriteTime] with the current time. I would like some advice on how I can do that once I copy the file. Below is my current code

```
$Date = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy-dddd HH-mm"
$FROM = Get-ChildItem "C:\Testing\DeviceLists\" -Recurse
$TO   = Get-ChildItem "C:\Transfer" 
$LOGS = "C:\Testing\logs\" 
#$d = [datetime](Get-ItemProperty -Path C:\Transfer -Name LastWriteTime).lastwritetime
$d = Get-ChildItem C:\Transfer\ -File | Sort-Object -Property -CreationTime | Select-Object -Last 1

foreach($item in $from){
    $fromdate = $item.LastWriteTime
    $ToFileInfo = $TO | where Name -eq $item.Name
    if((Get-date $fromdate) -ge (Get-Date $d.LastWriteTime))
    {
        #Move the files that are greater than destination date
        copy-item $item.FullName -Destination "C:\Transfer" -Force 
        #change lastwritetime of copied file 
        $item.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date)
        Add-Content "$Logs\Log - $Date.txt" -Value "$item has been copied"
    }
    else 
    {
        #log that file is having an error or lesser time 
    }
};

Add-Content "$Logs\Log - $Date.txt" -Value "All files have been copied"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-PassThru` to make `Copy-Item` return the copied file info, then set the timestamp on that:

```
$newItem = Copy-Item $item.FullName -Destination "C:\Transfer" -Force -PassThru
$newItem.LastWriteTime = Get-Date
```

Comment: for some reason it is now changing all my files that are stamped for the month of the last file time in the copied folder. For eg. if the last file date time in the destination folder is 30/08/2022 08:22, it is copying the files greater than that date but updating all the files for that month as well. so all files for month 08 are getting updated with the time

Comment: I found the issue, the last time of the file from my code is picking from the last file in the folder so if the order is sorted it still picks from the last file in the folder. I'll need to compare all the files in the destination folder and then pick the last time.